# Firefox is not prompting for client certificate

Tags: ssl, firefox, client-certificates

- Firefox 91.12.0
- Windows 10 Enterprise for Virtual Desktops version 21H2 build 19044.1766
- Visual Studio 2022 V 17.1.6
- C#
- .NET Core 6.0
- System.Security,Cryptography.OpenSsl 5.0.0 nuget package

I am creating a certificate authority to programmatically generate client certificates. The CA (and the intermediate CA) is imported into windows. I have created an website in IIS that uses that certificate, and it works fine with all three browsers (edge, chrome, firefox).

I created another website in IIS to require client certificates, and I used my CA application to generate a client certificate. I imported that certificate using chrome, and I see that cert in MMC "Certificates - Current User" under Personal->Certificates. Both Chrome and Edge prompt for the certificate, and when I select it, it grants me access to the site, and I can see the index.html content.

Firefox does not prompt me for the certificate. In Firefox advanced preferences:

- security.osclientcerts.autoload = true
- security.enterprise_roots.enabled = true

I have tried to import the PFX file my app generates, within Firefox, and it prompts me for a password, but it issues the error message "The PKCS #12 operation failed for unknown reasons" ... which tells me precisely nothing.

In my research I have seen comments about certificate fields being encoded with "printable
strings" rather than UTF8, but I can find no way to control this, or even control it in anyway.

So what am I doing wrong? What special thing is it that Firefox needs that it isn't getting?

Edit: The issue I mentioned before, [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1569086/firefox-does-not-offer-client-certificate-ssl-error-handshake-failure-alert), was that the cert did not contain PrintableStrings. I confirmed using ASN.1 Decoder that my cert does in fact use PrintableStrings for everything in the cert.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that when I generated the certificate it ***had the same serial number*** as the certificate from the CA. I changed the number to 9, and restarted Firefox, and it prompted me for the cert.

So ... apparently duplicate serial numbers among certs from the same CA are a problem for Firefox.